# Selecting specific return value from polar

Tags: maple

If I do this conversion to polar form

input:
num = polar(3+I*3)

returns:
num = polar(3sqrt(2),1/4*pi)

How can I select the 1/4*pi part of the return value?

I believe it should be possible to select num[1] or similar, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num := polar(3+I*3);

                                         1/2   Pi
                         num := polar(3 2   , ----)
                                                4

argument(num);

                                    Pi
                                   ----
                                     4
```

Given that `num` is a function call to polar, then its second operand is the argument.

```
op(2,num);

                                     Pi
                                    ----
                                      4
```

Note that you don't necessarily need to get to polar form before being able to access the argument of the complex numeric value.

```
argument(3+I*3);

                                     Pi
                                    ----
                                      4
```

Comment: Answered the question very accurately.